# How to implement a currency input directive for ion-input

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-directives

**Update**: *Originally though the problem was in the implementation of the ControlValueAccessor and subsequently determined the issue was about applying the ControlValueAccessor to child elements. Question edited to reflect.*

I want to provide an attribute directive that would show a currency value in 'dollar' format (e.g. 10.00) but would be stored in the underlying model as cents (e.g. 1000).

```
<!-- cost = 1000 would result in text input value of 10.00
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cost" name="cost" currencyInput>
<!-- or in Ionic 2 -->
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cost" name="cost-ionic" currencyInput>
```

Previously in AngularJS 1.x I would use parse and render in the directives link function as follows:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.directives').directive('ndDollarsToCents', ['$parse', function($parse) {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                var listener = function() {
                    element.val((value/100).toFixed(2));
                };

                ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                    return Math.round(parseFloat(viewValue) * 100);
                });

                ctrl.$render = function() {
                    element.val((ctrl.$viewValue / 100).toFixed(2));
                };

                element.bind('change', listener);
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

In Ionic 2/Angular 2 I implemented this using the ControlValueAccessor interface has follows:

```typescript
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

const CURRENCY_VALUE_ACCESSOR = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyInputDirective),
  multi: true
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[currencyInput]',
    host: {
        '(input)': 'handleInput($event.target.value)'
     },
     providers: [ CURRENCY_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterViewInit
{
    onChange = (_: any) => {};
    onTouched = () => {};
    inputElement: HTMLInputElement = null;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private elementRef: ElementRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        let element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

        if(element.tagName === 'INPUT')
        {
            this.inputElement = element;
        }
        else
        {
             this.inputElement = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }

    handleInput(value : string)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            value = String(Math.round(parseFloat(value) * 100));
        }

        this.onChange(value);
    }


    writeValue(value: any): void
    {
        if (value)
        {
            value = (parseInt(value) / 100).toFixed(2);
        }

        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.inputElement, 'value', value);
    }
}
```

While this works fine when applied to a straight input element when applied to an ion-input it does not function. Is there a way I can get the ControlValueAccessor to apply to the child input element of the ion-input?

Comment: input and output?? sample

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the ControlAccessorValue approach was suitable for a plain `<input>` element I could not get the directive to act as a control accessor for the `<input>` child element of the `<ion-input>` directive (interested in an solution for this).

Alternatively the following directive, achieves the desired result when applied to a `<ion-input>` or plain `<input>`:

```typescript
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[currencyInput]',
    host: {
        '(input)': 'handleInput($event.target.value)'
    },
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective implements AfterViewInit
{

    @Input('currencyInput') currency: number;
    @Output('currencyInputChange') currencyChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
    inputElement: HTMLInputElement = null;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        let element = this.el.nativeElement;

        if(element.tagName === 'INPUT')
        {
            this.inputElement = element;
        }
        else
        {
            this.inputElement = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.inputElement, 'value', (this.currency/100).toFixed(2));
        }, 150);
    }

    handleInput(value: string)
    {
        let v : number = Math.round(parseFloat(value) * 100)
        this.currencyChange.next(v);
    }
}
```

And then applying it on the element as follows:

```
<ion-input type="text" name="measured_cost" [(currencyInput)]="item.cost">
```

The `setTimeout` is required to ensure that the input field is initialised by the `CurrencyInputDirective` rather than ionic (I welcome a better alternative).

This works fine but it only provides one way flow i.e. if the `item.cost` is changed outside of the input element it is not reflected in the input element value. This issue can be addressed using a setter method for `currencyInput` as shown in the following this less performant solution:

```typescript
import { Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[currencyInput]',
    host: {
        '(input)': 'handleInput($event.target.value)'
    },
})
export class CurrencyInputDirective implements AfterViewInit
{
    _cents: number;
    myUpdate: boolean = false;
    inputElement: HTMLInputElement = null;
    @Input('currencyInput')
    set cents(value: number) {
        if(value !== this._cents)
        {
            this._cents = value;
            this.updateElement();
        }
    }
    @Output('currencyInputChange') currencyChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) { }

    ngAfterViewInit()
    {
        let element = this.el.nativeElement;

        if(element.tagName === 'INPUT')
        {
            this.inputElement = element;
        }
        else
        {
            this.inputElement = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.inputElement, 'value', (this._cents/100).toFixed(2));
        }, 150);
    }

    handleInput(value: string)
    {
        let v : number = Math.round(parseFloat(value) * 100);
        this.myUpdate = true;
        this.currencyChange.next(v);
    }

    updateElement()
    {
        if(this.inputElement)
        {
            let startPos = this.inputElement.selectionStart;
            let endPos = this.inputElement.selectionEnd;

            this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.inputElement, 'value', (this._cents/100).toFixed(2));
            if(this.myUpdate)
            {
                this.inputElement.setSelectionRange(startPos, endPos);
                this.myUpdate = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not use `ControlValueAccessor` to achieve this. Use the below code

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[currency]'
})
export class CurrencyDirective{

    constructor(
        private renderer: Renderer2,
        private el: ElementRef
    ){}

    @HostListener('keyup') onKeyUp() {
      this.el.nativeElement.value=this.el.nativeElement.value/100;
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.value)
     console.log('some thing key upped')

    }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SvreLCN3r6008xnyJo4j)**

Comment: That doesn't quite provide the required functionality as you type in the field it changes the value out from under you. What I'm after is on initialisation the value of the text field to be set to the value of the model/100 and subsequently when the text field value is changed directly the model value is set to the text field value * 100.

Comment: I didn't get you. When init u need something and changes u need some other thing? Or on focus or on blur

Comment: The model value will be pulled from the database in cents format I.e 1000. When the text field is initialised its value will then be set as 10.00. From there any keypress event from the textfield will set the model value to the textfield value multiplied by 100.